# PhpStorm Find all Instances in current remote file

Tags: phpstorm

I am trying to get a list of search results for a string in the current file which is opened from a remote host. CTRL F only highlights the instances in the doc but does not give me an easy overview. If I have a file downloaded to my project folder I can press CTRL SHIFT F for "find in path" and then CTRL ENTER to open the find window. complicated but better than nothing.

Is there a simple "find all in current file" command, disregarding whether its a project file or a remote file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `All` button on Find toolbar and it will list all found entries in a standard "Find Results" toolwindow.

[image]

[image]